# Bazel extension file not found error when installing TensorFlow in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, bazel

I currently have an error while installing tensorflow with python 3. Previously I had successfully installed tensorflow with python 2, and that was after I commented out several sections for ios/android. I decided to copy over the exact tensorflow files that worked for the python 2, and reconfigured the settings to suit it for python 3. Is this correct? Because I figured the configurations would be overwritten if I reconfigure the same files, and the edited files I require for TensorFlow to work will still be present.

Here is my error code:

> error loading package 'bazel-tensorflow/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/docker/testdata': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '//tools/build_defs/docker:docker.bzl': BUILD file not found on package path.

Comment: By "installing" do you mean "build from source and then install"? It would be helpful to see the full sequence of commands you are doing so that I can try reproducing the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right I meant building from the master branch source.

Comment: did you run ./configure before building?

Comment: Yes. To be specific I got this error while configuring.

Comment: What's 1) your OS, 2) your bazel version?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, but typing "bazel version" does not give me the bazel version. I only recently installed bazel 2 days ago.

Comment: It is weird that "bazel version" doesn't give the version information. It should say something like "Build label: 0.x.y". I wonder if it is related

Comment: Yes, surprisingly it doesn't show the build label.

Comment: Your problem sounds like some sort of environment / dependency issue.
Try the following things: 1) clone or pull the latest TensorFlow source from GitHub, 2) make sure you install the latest version of bazel. See here for how TensorFlow's CI servers does it: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/install/install_bazel.sh  If all these fail, try the docker approach to build the pip package (whl file). See this README file for details: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/README.md

Comment: After the docker pip build, the whl file can be found in the directory pip_test/whl.